# Array as parametar

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I don't understand, and can't find on google how do I call my method, whose parameter is an array?

```
private static void printArray(double a[],int p){
        int count[]=new int[p];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<p;j++){
                if((a[i]>=100/p*j) && (a[i]<100/p*(j+1))){
                    count[j]++;
```

for example, how do I call this method in my main method:

I tried `printArray({1,2,3,4,5},5);` and it's not working or `printArray([10],5);` but still doesn't work?

Comment: `new Double[]{1.1,1.2}`

Answer (score 4):

You would first need to create an array.  Like you did here:

```
int count[]=new int[p];
```

In your example something like

```
double myArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Then you would pass the variable name to your method like:

```
printArray(myArray, someInt);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you man! I appreciate it

Comment: No prob.  Did it work?

Comment: yes :) Actually I created method double [] createArray(int n)..
But was so stupid, didn't know to use it with another method.

Comment: Great.  Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your calls is:

- `printArray({1,2,3,4,5},5);` - {1,2,3,4,5} as a parameter is not recognized. You need to create an array which is of type double.
- `printArray([10],5);` - [10] is also not recognized by the compiler and is not the correct way to pass double[].

This is how to initialize an array inline in java: 
`new double[]{1,2,3,4,5}`

So, this is how you call it:
`printArray(new double[]{1,2,3,4,5},5);`

Comment: double[] is not the same type as Double[]. And `new Double[](1,2,3,4,5)` is not valid Java.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

you can call your method like this, if the method is in the same class with method main.

```
 double[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
 printArray(arr,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

[10] is not a variable. When you pass an array you do not need brackets. Just the variable name. For example:

```
double array1[] = {10,12,13};
printArray(array1);
```

Comment: That wouldn't compile.

Comment: @JBNizet array1 needs to be initialized.

Comment: And that's precisely what the OP is asking: how to initialize a double array and pass it to a method.

Comment: @JBNizet oops misread the question. Thanks for pointing that out